# Schengen visa canceled due to itinerary change?

Tags: visas, france, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

I applied and got a multi entry C Schengen visa from France valid for 3 months. My original trip was 
France- 5N, 
Austria- 3N, 
Czech Republic- 1N, 
Germany 6N, 
France- 1N 
However, we decided that we want to spend some time in Greece instead of France so now the itinerary is 
France- 1N, 
Greece- 4N, 
Austria- 4N, 
Czech Republic- 2N, 
Germany 4N 
France- 1N

At first I applied to France because I will be in Germany and France for the same amount of days and France is my port of entry. With the itinerary change, France is still my port of entry but I will be adding a different country and staying at some countries for longer/shorter that I  never mentioned to the embassy. Will they revoke my visa because I will be making these changes? I have heard stories about visas being canceled because the original hotel reservation was canceled. I am an Indian citizen living in the United States if that helps.

Comment: Highly unlikely, especially as your entry and exit point remains France and the duration is the same. Without border controls, your intra-Schengen itinerary is largely a black box. If you supplied hotel names, I would make a point of keeping the reservation at the first hotel on the itinerary. For what it's worth, I think the revised schedule will leave you quite exhausted.

Comment: So are you saying I should keep the original 5 day itinerary? Or I should cancel it and book the same hotel for the one night?

Comment: I think the one night. Unless you were planning to fly to Greece that same day you arrive.

Comment: You’ll be spending half your trip either travelling to or in an airport, or on a plane!

Comment: They **can** cancel your visa because under the changed itinerary you should not have applied to the French embassy. However it is unlikely they will even if they find out. Bottom line is there is **some** risk although minor. I have several times previously taken visas from French embassy and used it to go elsewhere without even going to France however I was not questioned at immigration. It could have ended badly if they did.